# Suddenly getting pink rendered texture on model

Tags: unity, textures, materials

Hey All I have been using this model in this project for a bit and everything was fine then suddenly this issue popped up and I am not sure what could be the cause. I am using a flatkit shader but even if I switch to a standard shader I am still seeing the pink lines. Wondering if this is something I messed up in the texture settings or the file itself ?

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the steps required to produce a minimal complete verifiable example? That would include a model file, and texture image, and shader/material settings that when used together exhibit the issue.

Comment: I don't think I am allowed to do that the model is purchased off the unity asset store :/

Comment: Then your next step is to reproduce the problem with a freely available model, or one you can list the steps to create.

Comment: Could it be a problem with the model itself? Perhaps a part of its texture is pink and is bleeding into an adjacent UV?

Comment: Is the texture a pdf?

Comment: So when I am looking at it in blender it is a uv map and that goes to a png image. @shingo. hmm ok phillip ill check that thanks ! I have since re-downloaded and created a new prefab in unity and this issue isn't happening. I was wondering what I could have done to cause it.